# How to check if CLCircularRegions intersect

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm developing an iOS app (with Swift) that keeps a log of a user's location history. As part of a search algorithm, I'd like to check if two `CLCircularRegions` intersect, but I can't seem to find a Core Location method or function to do it. `CLCircularRegion` has the `containsCoordinate` method, but that's not exactly what I need. I also know that Map Kit includes functions to check for intersecting `MKMapRects`, but since I'm not actually working with maps, those solutions don't seem ideal.

I hope I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. How can I check if two `CLCircularRegions` intersect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind small inaccuracies, you can assume that the regions are small enough that the curvature of the Earth is negligible therefore the regions can be treated as planes.

In this case, just check whether the distance of the two center points is smaller than the sum of the radii. Two circles intersect if and only if their centers are closer than the sum of their radii.

```
CLCircularRegion r1, r2;

const double meanEarthRad = 6371009;
const double metersPerDegree = 2 * M_PI * meanEarthRad / 360;

double dLat = r2.center.latitude - r1.center.latitude;
double dLon = r2.center.longitude - r1.center.longitude;

double actCenterDist = hypot(dLat, dLon) * metersPerDegree;
double minCenterDist = r1.radius + r2.radius;

if (actCenterDist < minCenterDist) {
    // the regions intersect
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, because the regions I'm dealing with are small enough that the Earth's curvature is negligible. This answer saved me from a lot of stress; I was about to try something ridiculous, like trying to compare the coordinate equations of the circles.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode I've added some sample code (just in order to confuse you!)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2** version of *The Paramagnetic Croissant*'s answer

```
extension CLCircularRegion {
    func intersects(_ r2: CLCircularRegion) -> Bool {
        let r1 = self
        let meanEarthRad: Double = 6371009
        let metersPerDegree = 2 * Double.pi * meanEarthRad / 360

        let dLat = r2.center.latitude - r1.center.latitude
        let dLon = r2.center.longitude - r1.center.longitude

        let actCenterDist = hypot(dLat, dLon) * metersPerDegree
        let minCenterDist = r1.radius + r2.radius

        return actCenterDist < minCenterDist
    }
}
```